# CodeIgniter: Displaying Dynamic Titles issues

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can someone help me out with this piece of code.

I have a template set up like this:

system/core/Loader.php :

```
public function template($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        $template  = $this->view('includes/header', array(), $return);
        $template  = $this->view('includes/navigation', array(), $return);
        $template .= $this->view($view, $vars, $return);
        $template .= $this->view('includes/footer', array(), $return);

        if ($return)
        {
            return $template;
        }
    }
```

It works perfect but when I try this to display a dynamic title, it doesn't want to display the title. I guess because the data is passed to content_home rather then to includes/header:

my controller:

```
public function home() {
        $this->load->model("model_get");
        $data["page_title"] = "Home Page";
        $data["results"] = ($this->model_get->getData("home"));
        $this->load->template("content_home",$data);
    }
```

includes/header.php

```
<title><?php echo (isset($page_title)) ? $page_title : 'Default title text'; ?> </title>
```

Any ideas how to work it out ??

Thanks : )

Comment: `I guess because the data is passed to content_home rather then to includes/header` you know the problem, then why ask for help? You have to pass the proper array to the appropriate view.

Comment: Yeah but how to that ? How to pass the data in the fucntion template ??

Comment: Unrelated, but as a basic rule, you shouldn't change anything in the `systems` folder - you can do the everything from the `application` folder alone - try extending CI classes (etc)

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented dynamic titles in an even simpler way:

**Controller:**

```
$data['header_data'] = array('title'=>'Foo bar');
$data['page'] = "login";
$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

**View - template.php**

```
$this->load->view('includes/header', $header_data);
$this->load->view('pages/'.$page);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

We have two folders in views - includes and pages.
includes folder: header.php, footer.php (etc..)
pages folder: login.php, profile.php (etc..)

**views/includes/header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title><?=$title?></title>
 </head>
...
```

This way, you can use the same template to load all your pages. You may send data other than the title too!

Comment: hmmmm. i like that you are separating the header data like that - could especially be tidy if you are creating a complicated navigation bar with arrays etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your views folder make a template file like this,
we'll call it template_web.php

```
<?php 

// the preset view files for your template
$this->load->view('includes/header');     
$this->load->view('includes/navigation'); 

// in this example we will have our content view files in a folder called 'web' 
$templatefolder = 'web/';

// this is where you can pass in 'content' view files that are unique for the page 
// this example has 3 placeholders you can put as many as you need 

if(isset($content01))
$this->load->view($templatefolder.$content01);

if(isset($content02))
$this->load->view($templatefolder.$content02);

if(isset($content03))
$this->load->view($templatefolder.$content03);

 // preset template footer file 
 $this->load->view('includes/footer');
```

ok now in your controller methods

```
// data you want to pass to your header  
$data['page_title'] = 'Awesome Home Page';

// other data
$data['bigbagofdata'] = $this->bigBagOf->awesomeData ; 

// the name of the view files 
$data['content01'] = 'homepage';
$data['content02'] = 'homepage_banner'; 

// your template 
$this->load->view( 'template_web', $data );
```

data can be passed to any of the view files. and its very easy to set up different templates this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$template  = $this->view('includes/header', $view, $return);
```

instead of

```
$template  = $this->view('includes/header', array(), $return);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your `$data["page_title"]` variable in your header view, then you should pass it into your header view:

**change this line:**

`$template  = $this->view('includes/header', array(), $return);`

to

`$template  = $this->view('includes/header', $vars, $return);`

Answer (score 0):

I think MrMarchello finds oout the real issue. the issue is not passing the $data variable to header.

```
$data['title'] = "Edit User";
$this->load->view('template/header', $data);
$this->load->view('user/edit_member', $data);
$this->load->view('template/footer');
```

Hope this help you a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

In your config file add this parameter:

```
$config['pageTitle'] = 'Book Store';
```

In template page :

```
<title><?=$this->config->config["pageTitle"]?></title>
```

In any page you like change this config in action:

```
$this->config->config["pageTitle"] = $detail[0]['Title'];
```

Every time you can change the title easily.